# React - jsx --watch does nothing after first conversion

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't use in browser `JSXTransformer.js` even for development, because i am using `require.js` for loading modules. 
When i run `jsx --watch src/ build/`, actually just one `jsx->js` conversion is performed against files in `src` directory, but subsequently, if i change any file in `src` directory, nothing happened, no translation `jsx->js` (like if `jsx --watch` didn't noticed any changes).

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. This worked once and only once:

jsx --watch ../src/jsx ../src/js

Comment: Are you running the r.js optimizer or any other JS-related build tools in addition to JSX compilation?

Answer (score 20):

Same happened to me.

Try this command line:

```
jsx --watch -x jsx src/ build/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but this helped:

> jsx --watch ./scr ./build

Answer (score 0):

Actually it happens when you are trying to start the command from wrong folder or set the wrong path to folder from which you want to build (e.g. "src/"). Write path depends on you directory's structure. Best way to find out write path is to print the command "jsx --watch " and then use Tab to get path to directory you need or just make sure the current folder in terminal contains build/ and src/ folders.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, and maybe it's because I don't really understand how "--watch" is supposed to work.  What I initial did was this:  open terminal, punch in "watch" command (e.g. "jsx --watch /src /build).  As soon as I did that, the terminal spit back something like "helloworld.js was built".  All good.

Then I closed the terminal window and nothing worked after that.

Then I re-opened the terminal, re-typed the command, and the watch command worked.

Then I closed the terminal, and it stopped working.

I'm sensing a pattern here.  Is the JSX watch command only active while the containing terminal window is open?  I assumed "watch" was a "set it once and forget it" command, but it sounds like it's more ephemeral than that?

Comment: It is something that you should run once but if you close the terminal you kill the process. so you should run the command and keep the terminal minimized.

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue probably bacause of the suffix of the files is `jsx` and not `js` the jsx command not recognize `.jsx` files.

You can do as user2038099 said:

`jsx --watch -x jsx src/ build/`

> -x, --extension   File extension to assume when resolving module identifiers

or you can change the suffix of the files in the src folder to `.js`.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4269

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem running Ubuntu 14.04. The jsx command would not give any feedback regardless what arguments I passed it. I eventually ended up uninstalling node entirely and installed using the instructions for Ubuntu at https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

I was previously on nodejs v0.10.28, but now that I'm on nodejs v0.12.7 everything is working fine.